# Eclipse Plugin - TreeViewer display large amount of Text

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, treeview

I am currently writing on a Plugin that uses a view with a TreeViewer. The thing is, as content for my Nodes I get plain HTML. I would like to display the HTML styled or, if not possible, the simple plain text without any HTML. But the issue I run into is that the TreeViewer is not displaying enough text.

[image: HTML is not complete]

[image]

As you can see the HTML is not completly displayed and that everyting is only one line is not pretty aswell. I would like to have a box or something that can display the text (doesnt matter if the box does not support the HTML-styling, I can do this from hand).

Currently I'm using a [LabelProvider](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/LabelProvider.html) that is returning the Text of a Node as string (and from what I can see this is the only possible Option with a [LabelProvider](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/LabelProvider.html)).

As workaround I could only think of cutting the text into serval nodes but I would like to know if there are better options out there ;)

Comment: TreeViewer does like having rows with different heights so although it is possible to have a row with multiple lines all the nodes including the top level would be the same height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's your own LabelProvider, you can truncate or manipulate the text shown however you wish. Since it ultimately ends up as a native control, you're basically stuck with text label with a single image (plus whatever IColorLabelProvider offers) as long as you're using a tree control.

You could experiment with the Figures from the GEF project or the Nebula CompositeTable as alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a editor to show the content, this would be appropriate with your requirement. View can also be think for it. tableviewer clould also be least choice. TreeViewer generaly use to deal with hierarchical data.

Answer (score 1):

There are several label providers available in Eclipse in the `org.eclipse.jface.viewers` package. You can choose to implement your own or extend one of them to choose your need.

Looking at the image, I would recommend to display only few words in the tree and the entire content of the node could be in a different pane/tool tip.